# Which manga chapters correspond to The seven deadly sins wrath of the gods episodes?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Which manga chapters correspond to the seven deadly sins wrath of the God's episodes?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd season of *Nanatsu no Taizai* currently has two arcs: the Memories of the Holy War arc and the Corand arc. From the [wiki](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_Guide),

> Memories of the Holy War arc is the [fourteenth arc](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Memories_of_the_Holy_War_arc) in the series, lasting from the **198th chapter to the 218th chapter**...Corand arc is the [fifteenth arc](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Corand_arc) in the series, lasting from the **219th chapter to the 233th chapter**.